# How to change button colour alternate selection of button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

this is the code i am using ,**selectindex is BOOL**

```
if(!selectindex)
    {
        click.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"];

        selectindex=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        click.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

        selectindex=NO;
    }
```

My Problem is when user select my button its changing colour properly,when user try to select another button its continue with previous bool value.

->My requirement is when user click the button the colour have to change.

->Second when user select the same button the colour have to change.

->button placed inside tableview each button have tag, i am tried to change using tag value but failed.Any one please help me....

Third Party Tableview Header section:

```
- (UIView *)mTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView *viewHeader=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width,tableView.frame.size.height)];

    UIButton *btnClick;
 lblHead=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,3,150, 50)];
        btnClick=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,30, 30)];

    [btnClick addTarget:self action:@selector(touchup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnClick.clipsToBounds = YES;
    btnClick.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    btnClick.layer.cornerRadius=btnClick.frame.size.height/2;
    [btnClick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnClick.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    btnClick.tag=section;
    [viewHeader addSubview:btnClick];
    return viewHeader;
}
```

this is i expect...[image]

select index initially->**no**.

when user select the button colour changed.

now that selectIndex value is **yes**;
when user try to select another button ,**the selectIndex values continue with true**.So when user click the button second time its colour has been changed.
  **Please Note The button selection should be multiple:**

Comment: in which method you did you write this code? 'didselectrowAtIndexpath'?

Comment: @jamil65able i have updated mycode as per your requirement....

Comment: small question, if you are setting the buttom image? what is the point in setting the background color ?

Comment: i have give you example exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found answer thanks for your reply friends....

```
-(void)touchup:(UIButton*)click
{

    if(click.selected==NO)
    {
        click.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"];
        click.selected=YES;
    }
    else
    {
         click.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        click.selected=NO;
    }

}
```

That selected default state is NO.

```
@property(nonatomic,getter=isSelected) BOOL selected;                                // default is NO may be used by some subclasses or by application
```

Answer (score 2):

You should save state for each cell in dictionary or in  your class

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

       return [yourArray  count];
}
```

And in

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 if(dictionary[@“selectindex”] ==NO )
{

         click.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"];
         NSLog(@"kishore kumar”); 
         [dictionary setValue:YES forKey:@“ selectindex”];

    }else{

        click.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        [dictionary setValue:NO forKey:@“selectindex”];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please describe in detail, I giving answer as per my understanding.

First take one `NSMutableArray *arr_index;`

On button click store the current IndexPath to `arr_index` & reload table

In cellforRow method of tableview write below code

```
if([arr_index containsObject:indexPath])
{
 // change your button bgColor
}
else
{
// Default Color for button
}
```

Comment: You can handle button action event & change bgcolor or button bg image in cellforrow method  as you wish. is it work for you bro..?

Comment: no this not my requirement bro,my app selection should be multiple,and if same button clicked colour have to change as previous color..

Comment: on button action method you can remove store index from array if it's exist  & reload the table it's done bro.

Answer (score 0):

//chekMarkArray initially contain 0.//[chekMarkArray addObject:@(0)];

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 //………
    BOOL selectindex = [[chekMarkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    if (!selectindex) {
        testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];//[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"];
    }else{
        testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    //………..
return cell;
```

}

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
BOOL currentStatus = [[chekMarkArray objectAtIndex:button.tag] boolValue];
//deselect all selection
for (int i=0;i<chekMarkArray.count;i++) {
    [chekMarkArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@(0)];
}
//select current button
[chekMarkArray replaceObjectAtIndex:button.tag withObject:@(!currentStatus)];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Comment: do you need only one button selection at a time?

Comment: no multiple selection and if the same button clicks again then the colour have to change as initial stage colour ..

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with ease following this method. 
Each button has a property called 'selected'. You can use this instead of creating a BOOL variable for each of your individual buttons.
Assuming your button name is 'click', simply check state of button and set colour by

```
if(click.selected){
    click.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"];
}
else{
    click.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
}
```

Since selected is a property and its BOOL value is handled by its inbuilt functions, you don't have to set it to YES or NO.

EDIT:

Found an easier method.
Add images of selected and unselected buttons to your project as resources and set this.

`[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
`

Comment: where are you running this check?

Comment: Make an IBAction from interface builder in your view controller. And put this code inside it instead of using addTarger:

Comment: If you are using IBAction, make sure to change button name to 'sender' or whatever name you pass to the function.

Comment: what are you passing to touchup: selector?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90231/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-meharoof-najeeb).

Answer (score 0):

check [UITreeView](https://github.com/varun-naharia/UITreeView) it has the functionality